# Unable to create firefox section selenium grid which is hosted on docker

Tags: selenium, protractor, selenium-grid, selenium-firefoxdriver

Please check the details below:

I update - geckodriver: geckodriver-v0.20.1 up to date

Error:

```
firefox_1       | 11:39:06.089 INFO [RemoteSession$Factory.lambda$performHandshake$0] - Started new session a16899ff-8ef3-40b4-a7a3-406861b95c50 (org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService)
nodeSetup_1     | [e2e] [11:39:06] E/launcher - Unable to parse new session response: {"value":{"sessionId":"a16899ff-8ef3-40b4-a7a3-406861b95c50","capabilities":{"acceptInsecureCerts":false,"browserName":"firefox","browserVersion":"60.0.2","moz:accessibilityChecks":false,"moz:headless":false,"moz:processID":71,"moz:profile":"/tmp/rust_mozprofile.EvUy5THtLClM","moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin":false,"moz:webdriverClick":true,"pageLoadStrategy":"normal","platformName":"linux","platformVersion":"3.19.0-25-generic","rotatable":false,"timeouts":{"implicit":0,"pageLoad":300000,"script":30000},"webdriver.remote.sessionid":"a16899ff-8ef3-40b4-a7a3-406861b95c50"}}}
nodeSetup_1     | [e2e] [11:39:06] E/launcher - WebDriverError: Unable to parse new session response: {"value":{"sessionId":"a16899ff-8ef3-40b4-a7a3-406861b95c50","capabilities":{"acceptInsecureCerts":false,"browserName":"firefox","browserVersion":"60.0.2","moz:accessibilityChecks":false,"moz:headless":false,"moz:processID":71,"moz:profile":"/tmp/rust_mozprofile.EvUy5THtLClM","moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin":false,"moz:webdriverClick":true,"pageLoadStrategy":"normal","platformName":"linux","platformVersion":"3.19.0-25-generic","rotatable":false,"timeouts":{"implicit":0,"pageLoad":300000,"script":30000},"webdriver.remote.sessionid":"a16899ff-8ef3-40b4-a7a3-406861b95c50"}}}
nodeSetup_1     | [e2e]     at doSend.then.response (/usr/src/app/serenityjs/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:445:19)
```

Code

```
Protractor conf:
multiCapabilities: [
    {
      browserName: 'firefox',
      firefoxOptions: {
        args: ['--headless',
        'seleniumProtocol=Selenium'
       ]
      },
      'moz:firefoxOptions': {
        args: [ '--headless',
          'seleniumProtocol=Selenium'
        ]
      }
     }

   ],
```

Comment: What is the target FF version.

Comment: @demouser123 "browserVersion":"60.0.2"

Answer (score 0):

Probably you set up capabilities in a wrong way. Try this one:

```
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'firefox',
  'moz:firefoxOptions': {
    'args': ['--headless']
  }
},
```

Comment: Still facing this issue while connecting on selenium-grid on docker

[e2e] [15:00:03] E/launcher - WebDriverError: Unable to parse new session response: {"value":{"sessionId":"76cd1b1a-17d7-4945-831a-9a48c67362b3","capabilities":{"acceptInsecureCerts":false,"browserName":"firefox","browserVersion":"60.0.2","moz:accessibilityChecks":false,"moz:headless":false,"moz:processID":71,

Comment: It's resolved. There was an issue in the node packages and I updated everything latest including protractor and it's started working.